# Get Javascript Variables Via Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

Assume that I have a html file in which the javascript code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test1 = 1;
    var test2 = 2;
    var tset3 = 3;
</script>
```

How do I get the javascript variables via Excel VBA for use in Excel VBA macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can read the html file first, use `open file` in VBA and save it in a `string` variable.
2. Then, you should parse the `string` variable line
   by line to get any substring `var xxx = yyy`, use `instr` and `loop` method to get the variable name and its value.